# Import Oracle unicode data with OLE DB Source and destination in SSIS 2015

Tags: ssis, oracle-12c, sql-server-2017

My issue is identical to [this post on mssqltips.com](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1393/import-excel-unicode-data-with-sql-server-integration-services/), however my issue is importing from Oracle, not Excel.

I get all the way to the bottom where I need to map the output columns from my data conversion to the destination. I have mapped these columns yet I still get the error on my source task.

[image]

I have also tried [just about every answer on this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547539/ssis-convert-between-unicode-and-non-unicode-error) to no avail.

How can I migrate this table from Oracle to SQL Server using SSIS?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify, you have Unicode columns in Oracle you want to map to Non-Unicode columns in SQL Server? If yes, you should simply be able to add your Oracle source in SSIS, a data conversion task to convert from WSTR to STR data types and then your SQL Server destination, mapping the converted columns to the destination columns.

Comment: Well I guess it is just that simple. Maybe I was doing things out of order or trying to change the data types before they were ready... at any rate I will add an answer later.  Steps for success, add Oracle source and point to the source table, add the conversion and change the WSTR to STR data types. Then point that to the SQL Server destination.

Comment: Maybe it isn't just that simple. I have repeated this process, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for the table in Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: The initial answer by MLivingston was valid. Why not import as NVARCHAR (which supports Unicode characters) in SQL Server? This would imply the use of WSTR in SSIS. Why the transformation to STR/VARCHAR?

Comment: honestly I think this may be the underlying issue on a number of problems I've been having. I am attempting a migration of the CLOB data to NVARCHAR.

Comment: Have you checked the data will fit? Oracle Clobs support more than 4Gb, SQL Nvarchar(Max) only support up to 2Gb.

Comment: I've had more success throwing Views over the top of troublesome Oracle tables and exporting from the Views instead.  Also, I'd suggest you check out [this datatype conversion table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/data-type-mapping-for-oracle-publishers?view=sql-server-2017) provided by Microsoft as well if you've not seen it yet.  You could be running up against implicit conversion errors without even realizing it as SSIS does not do the best job reporting these sort of issues.